# Left Join On table value that is not unique

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have two tables.

The first table is `meal_order` which has `order_id` and `bundle_id`. Now, `bundle_id` might be the same for multiple `order_id` and represents that those orders were at one point in one purchase cart and paid together (orders 3 and 4 have the same bundle 5).

```
order_id      bundle_id
-----------------------
   1             0
   2             0
   3             5
   4             5
```

The second table is `messages` with `message_id` and each message refers to either `order_id` (if its `bundle_id` is `0`) or `bundle_id` It also has `status` that represents whether the message was already seen or unseen.

```
message_id      order_id      bundle_id      status
---------------------------------------------------
   1               1             0             1
   2               2             0             1
   3               0             5             0
   4               0             5             0
```

I have a problem figuring out an SQL statement that will count the number of messages that have `status` =  `0` and belong to the same `bundle_id` ... in other words, I'm trying to find the way to DISTINCT `bundle_id` in LEFT JOIN `meal_order` table, however, this statement gives me `4` as a result instead of `2` :

```
SELECT COUNT(`message_id`) FROM `message` LEFT JOIN `meal_order` ON 
`message`.`order_id` = `meal_order`.`order_id` OR `message`.`bundle_id` = 
`meal_order`.`bundle_id` WHERE `message`.`status` = 0 GROUP BY 
`meal_order`.`bundle_id`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is `meal_order` part of the query at all? The (bundle_id, message count) answer (5, 2) can be determined solely by reading the second table. e.g. `SELECT bundle_id, COUNT(*) FROM messages WHERE bundle_id <> 0 AND status = 0 GROUP BY bundle_id`